# Intention for having CompletableFuture create separate thread for task when common pool does not support parallelism level >= 2

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

The Java doc for [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) states:

> All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task)

What is the reason for this decision of creating a thread for every single task? Why didn't they choose to create a pool with at least 2 workers instead, or why does the executor returned by `commonPool()` not have at least 2 workers?

Creating a thread for every task appears pretty inefficient to me.

Edit: There is also [JDK-8213115](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8213115) questioning the current behavior.

Comment: Usually common default pool has `nCPU - 1` threads, where `nCPU` is number of CPUs in your machine

Comment: Yes, but why did they decide to create separate threads for each task when your machine has only <= 2 CPUs?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `commonPool` could be synchronous. Instead of scheduling a task to run on a background thread, it might execute task when the `.join()` is called, directly on the thread that calls join. Such synchronous execution semantic can trivially lead to deadlocks, violating the contract of async methods. `CompletableFuture` works around potentially synchronous execution by spawning a new thread.

Note: both a `commonPool` with one brackground thread and a  synchronous `commonPool` with no background threads report `parallelism` of `1`. The thread hack is only required in the latter case, but no attempt is made to distinguish between the two cases.

Reference:

This change was made in the following commit:

> 8020435: CompletableFuture/Basic.java fails on single core machine
>
> https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/b1a10b8ed7bedb27ae25341602319a11a1225ee7

And what's the code at that time has to say about semantics of parallelism:

> Common pool parallelism. To allow simpler use and management
> when common pool threads are disabled, we allow the underlying
> common.parallelism field to be zero, but in that case still report
> parallelism as 1 to reflect resulting caller-runs mechanics.
>
> https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b1a10b8ed7bedb27ae25341602319a11a1225ee7/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#L1100-L1106

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for digging in the Git history of the OpenJDK. However, my question was mainly focused on "why not use an executor with 2 threads" instead of "why cannot use 1 thread" which your answer seems to be mainly about. In the meantime [Doug Lea had commented](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8213115?focusedId=14518572&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14518572) on the JDK enhancement request, saying that the behavior could potentially be changed in the future.

Comment: To clarify, there's no need to use an executor with >=2 threads, an executor with just a single thread would work fine. It's not 1 vs 2 threads, it is synchronous vs asynchronous execution.

And, yes, I'd argue that creating a pool with 1 thread would have been a better solution. I gather they wrote the smallest amount of code to get the tests passing. The behavior is indefensible otherwise and is clear bug.